# Return Not-Hidden Files

Tags: java, java-8

Prior to Java 8, this method would be used to create a list of hidden files:

```
    File[] hiddenFiles = new File("./directory/").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isHidden();
        }
    });
```

In Java 8, this can be shortened to:

```
File[] hiddenFiles = new File("./directory/").listFiles(File::isHidden);
```

Returning non-hidden files in the original code was a trivial change: `return file.!isHidden();` as a substitute for `return file.isHidden();`. I cannot recreate this functionality within a single line.

There is no `isNotHidden` function within the File class. Without creating one (or without deferring to the original, more verbose code), is there a way to recreate it using the new single-line style?

Comment: You can use `listFiles(f -> !f.isHidden())`. You can't negate a method reference.

Comment: **"Returning non-hidden files in the original code was a trivial change: `return file.!isHidden();`"** Not that trivial apparently, because that's not valid syntax. ;)

Comment: @daniu you can do via `Predicate.not(File::isHidden)` in java-11

Comment: Here's the original bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050818

Comment: @Michael: Hah, oops. Maybe I should start copying code in from my IDE rather than trying to remember it! It does look like that other answer hits mine though, thanks for that.

Comment: @Eugene for completeness sake: you can also negate the predicate itself in Java 8 if you assign it first: `Predicate<File> notHidden = File::isHidden; notHidden = notHidden.negate();`

Comment: @daniu or even `((Predicate<File>)File::isHidden).negate()`, but neither is as nice as the java-11 one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this,

```
File[] hiddenFiles = new File("c:/data").listFiles(f -> !f.isHidden());
```

Answer (score 3):

Coming in java-11 `Predicate.not`, until then you can't via a method reference

```
Predicate.not(File::isHidden)
```